# Robot framework-Source and target changing frames for drag and drop keyword

Tags: robotframework

Here the title itself is a question, so i have to drag and drop a plugin on my web page and using robot framework. the problem is the address of the source from where i am picking the element and placing it have different frames. what can i do in this case?

Comment: If the Drag and Drop Keyword is not working because of the frame, you can always try Drag and Drop By Offset http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Drag%20And%20Drop%20By%20Offset

Comment: What have you tried and what did you observe?

Comment: hi @A.Kootstra, I have to drop one element from one frame and drop it to other and moving it showing me below error: Element locator: 'xpath=(//h3[@class=''])' did not match any elements- this is the XPath of the element where i want to move the source element.

Comment: hi @cris, drag, and drop is giving me pass result but the problem is i have to verify for the element which i have moved and that is showing me that Element is not visible which i have moved.

Comment: Have you tried to use Wait Until Keyword Succeeds? Something like this: Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    1min    15s     Page Should Contain    xpath

Comment: Yes even that didn't work, i also tried with "Action chains". still no help. https://github.com/hmalphettes/robotframework-selenium2library-extensions